# How to filter properly my access logs with GoAccess?

Tags: linux, grep, zcat, goaccess

I want to generate a report with only the `POST /xmlrpc.php` requests, so I run the following command :

```
zcat access.log.*.gz | grep 'POST /xmlrpc.php' | goaccess -a -o report-xmlrpc.html
```

The results of the report are not all displayed (in the graph I see only 9 days, but I checked on the others logs and I have `POST /xmlrpc.php` requests almost every days (30 in total) ).

Am I using zat / grep / goaccess wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are parsing only *.gz logs, I assume you want to parse all of them (compressed and not compressed), try this instead:

```
zgrep -h 'POST /xmlrpc.php' access.log* | goaccess -a -o report-xmlrpc.html
```

Comment: But I tried your command, and... wow it works! :)

Why my command didn't work? `zgrep` is more or less the same as `zcat` + `grep` , isn't it ?

Comment: Please can i know why this does not work ? ` zcat -f /var/log/nginx/access.* | sed -n '/30\/Jun\/2020/,/30\/Jun\/2020/ p'  | goaccess -a --log-format=COMBINED
`